# how to POST json data and get responses from the local server by using cpprestsdk in c++

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, post, cpprest-sdk

Thank you for answering my asking.

About POST request in c++ with cpprestsdk.

I want to send json data to local server and get response from it by POST with cpprestsdk in c++. I made a program but it doesn't work. I can only send data but cannot get response data.
string fomrat OK! 
I can convert string and JSON Object mutually.

Please help me. 
I want to do it.

[pseudo source code like c# or Java]

```
string POST(string postData){;
  string receive = sendtoServer("http://localhost:8080/",postData);
  return receive;
}
```

[Linux or window command cURL]

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/ -d '{"age":20,"sex":male"}'
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>

using namespace web;  
using namespace web::http;  
using namespace web::http::client;  

auto POST(json::value postData){  
  http_client client(L"http://localhost:8080/");  
  auto receive = client.request(methods::POST, L"", postData.serialize(),   
     L"application/json").get().to_string().c_str();  
  printf("[DEBUG] receive = ");  
  std::wprintf(receive);  
  return  receive;  
}
```

Build success but it doesn't work.
I does't understand deeply Concurrent::task<>
so tell me my mistakes.
Thank you.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

try

> http_client client(L("http://localhost:8080/"));
>   auto receive =
>   client.request(methods::POST, L(""), postData.serialize(),
>        L("application/json")).get().to_string().c_str();

instead of

> http_client client(L"http://localhost:8080/");
>   auto receive =
>   client.request(methods::POST, L"", postData.serialize(),
>        L"application/json").get().to_string().c_str();

please note the use of brackets after "L".